# How do I make grease pencil outline ignore surrounding meshes?

Tags: grease-pencil

I am looking to solve an issue I'm experiencing when using a Grease Pencil Outline. Whenever there is a Mesh in front of the outline (from the camera's perspective) the outline will create a gap in itself noticeable by the camera. If there is some way to prevent the grease pencil outline from doing this I'd love to know.

It would be nice if I could have the grease pencil outline ignore all other meshes besides the one it is outlining and also ignore the position of the camera and just outline the whole mesh.

If you need any more info from me please let me know. I appreciate any help.

[image: Grease Pencil Outline Gap Issue Explained Screenshot]